# Calculate percentage SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database with products and the client need to enter a discount percentage.
The discount must be calculatet in the database so the query returns all prices - discount

How can i do that?

```
SELECT product.name sizes.height, sizes.width, product_sizes.price 
FROM   product_sizes as s 
JOIN   sizes ON s.sizeid = sizes.sizeid, product 
JOIN   product_sizes on product.productid = product_sizes.productid 
WHERE  product.productid=1
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a real query? The syntax does not look right.

Comment: i still don't get the question ^^ you want to have a calculated price in your result  ?!?!?

Comment: Yes thats what i mean Dwza

Comment: Your query is missing a comma after `product.name`. Doesn't it error out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i would do your query like this

```
SELECT p.name, s.height, s.width, ps.price 
FROM   product_sizes as ps, product as p, sizes as s 
WHERE  ps.sizeid = s.sizeid 
AND    p.productid = ps.productid
AND    p.productid=1
```

than you just have to calculate it in the select
try some like, its untested and i don't really know if this works, but it should...

```
SELECT p.name, s.height, s.width, (((ps.price/100)*x)+ps.price) as newPrice
FROM   product_sizes as ps, product as p, sizes as s 
WHERE  ps.sizeid = s.sizeid 
AND    p.productid = ps.productid
AND    p.productid=1
```

of course you have to put some in there where X is :)

what is with this rows ???.... (your source)

```
SELECT product.name sizes.height, sizes.width, product_sizes.price 
-------------------^ there is a comma missing
FROM   product_sizes as s 
JOIN   sizes ON s.sizeid = sizes.sizeid, product 
--------------------------------------------^ what is this ?
JOIN   product_sizes on product.productid = product_sizes.productid 
WHERE  product.productid=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can apply math operators in queries, such as multiplication and subtraction, assuming that the data are numeric.  From the sound of your question, it doesn't seem like you're aware of this, so this is an over-simplified example of things you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE Discount(
  Price DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO Discount
VALUES (23.4)
  , (20.9)
  , (16.8)

SELECT Price
  -- We're multiplying the price column by a discount percent of 10%
  , (Price * .10) Discount
  -- We're subtracting that discount amount from the price
  , Price - (Price * .10) PriceIncludingDiscount
FROM Discount
```

[SQL Fiddle demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3027/2)

In your case, your column `product_sizes.price` would be multiplied by the discount and subtracted from the price if you want to include the discounted amount, or simply multiplied by the discount percent if the discount is only what you're seeking (somewhat unclear in the question).